# MTM 2012 - Test Case status automatically reset to active

Tags: functional-testing, testcase, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

it does sound strange, but sometimes it happens that the status of a test case that was run a couple of days ago is automatically reset to active. 
Do you have any idea why, or where to start investigating?

I mention that:

- we did press save and close after the run (the test case was shown as passed for a couple of days);
- the test was not included in any other test suite;
- the test is a manual one;
- it did not happen for test belonging to suits that were marked as completed;
- We are using MTM 2012.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know a similar behavior regarding **automated** tests.

You will observe this if

- you associate your automated test run with a CI or nightly *build* AND
- if you set up a *Retention Policy" for these *build* AND
- if "*Build Delete Options*" are set like this:
  [image]

In this case the *test runs* will be deleted along with the *build*.
But it only applies to **automated** tests to my knowledge...

The behaviour you are observing is kind of similar one: your most recent **manual** test run gets deleted for some reason; that is the only reason I can imagine for a *test case* being reset to *active* "automatically".

Try to investigate in this direction; means what in your environment can cause **manual** *test run* to be deleted?

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me in the right direction, a step in the build configuration was to delete old test results